# tkinter sliders are stuck together

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, slider

I'm having trouble separating these 2 sliders. They seem to be tracking together, but the variables seem to no be unique, and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help?

```
import tkinter as tk

sBoard = tk.Tk()
sBoard.geometry("800x400")

ch1_Frame = tk.LabelFrame(sBoard, text = "CH 1", bd = 5)

ch1_val = 0
ch1 = tk.Scale(ch1_Frame, variable = ch1_val, from_ =100, to = 0, showvalue = 0, width = 25, length = 200)
ch1.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(ch1_Frame, text = "Power")
button1.pack()

ch1_Frame.place(x=25, y=50)

ch2_Frame = tk.LabelFrame(sBoard, text = "CH 2", bd = 5)

ch2_val = 0
ch2 = tk.Scale(ch2_Frame, variable = ch2_val, from_ =100, to = 0, showvalue = 0, width = 25, length = 200)
ch2.pack()

button2 = tk.Button(ch2_Frame, text = "Power")
button2.pack()

ch2_Frame.place(x=150, y=50)

sBoard.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable *must* be one of the tkinter variable types, for example an IntVar:

```
ch1_val = tk.IntVar()
ch1 = tk.Scale(ch1_Frame, variable = ch1_val, from_ =100, to = 0, showvalue = 0, width = 25, length = 200)
ch1.pack()
```